# quiero inyectar imagenes desde una api

Tags: javascript, api

```
function animeList() {

aniList = "https://api.trace.moe/search?url=https://images.plurk.com/32B15UXxymfSMwKGTObY5e.jpg"
fetch(aniList)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.result.forEach(animes => {
    const article = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
    ` <article><div class="container_img><img src=${animes.image} alt="personajes"></div></article>`
            );
            let main = document.querySelector("main")
            main.append("article")
        });
    })
}
animeList()
```

quiero inyectar la imagen; pero, solo se ejecuta el article, como letras nada mas, la idea es crear un article, el cual contenga un div, y que la imagen valla cambiando a medida que el bucle avanza y coloque diferentes imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Tienes error en la sintaxis:

1. Aqui no cerraste las comillas

```
<div class="container_img>
```

2. En tu `main.append` estas mandando un string en lugar de la variable.

```
main.append("article");
```

Por ultimo, te aconsejo mejorar la legibilidad y orden de tu código usando `map` y desestructuración.

```js
const url = "https://api.trace.moe/search";
const images = "https://images.plurk.com/32B15UXxymfSMwKGTObY5e.jpg";

fetch(`${url}?url=${images}`)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(({ result }) => {
    result.map(({ image }) => {
      console.log(image);
    });
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: gracias rene voy a tener en cuenta eso.

Comment: @deille, si la respuesta respondio tu pregunta, por favor, considera votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que aprendas como funciona el sitio y de paso ganar tu primer medalla.